# DecimalFormat with DecimalFormatSymbols problems in Java

Tags: java, string-formatting, decimalformat

i'm tring to format this BigDecimal value `621500.0` with thisDecimalFormatSymbols:

- zeroDigit = '0'
- groupingSeparator = '.'
- decimalSeparator = ','
- perMill = '‰'
- percent = '%'
- digit = '#'
- patternSeparator = ';'
- infinity = "∞"
- NaN = "�"
- minusSign = '-'
- currencySymbol = "¤"
- intlCurrencySymbol = "XXX"
- monetarySeparator = '.'
- exponential = 'E'
- locale = {Locale@59611} "en"
- currency = {Currency@59612} "XXX"
- serialVersionOnStream = 3

and i use this pattern `"€ #,0;€ -#,0"`
and when i execute `new DecimalFormat("€ #,0;€ -#,0", numberFormatSymbols).format(value)` it returns in **€ 6.2.1.5.0.0** instead of **€ 62150.0**. Any idea why? it is related to the locale? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve]? It'll make it easier for us to help you.